# How to change the language of the 'Reset Password' page

Tags: multi-language, password, language, reset

I have a WooCommerce powered WordPress website. In this website a user can login to order products, basic WooCommerce functionality.
The site is translated using qTranslate. I can translate everything, except the 'Reset password' page.
The basic website is in English. When a customer visits the website in French, then requests a new password, he is redirected to the WordPress page but in English. Is there a possibility I can alter this (e.g. using a querystring, calling an hook, ...)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are talking about the default `wp-login.php` page, it is full of localization code. [It should be translatable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress). I have not dealt with translation/internationalization enough to be much more help than that though.

Comment: I presume it is translatable. My problem is, when you're not logged in, how do you tell WordPress which language the login page (actually the reset password page) should be.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use either HTML5 or IP based geolocation, set a current_language cookie and you are good to go. Or even better if you just simply ask the user about it. Wordpress translation is not equal to multi-language by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can but only for one language. Ive had the same problem and then I realized that in Woocommerce/settings/accounts you will see a list of URL Endpoints of each page in My account one of them is Lost Password change the lost-password to the French language. Actually all the pages dont work with french in your case so its better to change the names of the who;e list. But this will cancel the english language for these pages. Youll still have the same problem but in the opposite language.